# How to automatically segue from one viewcontroller to another after 5 secs

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view Controller, I have named it Home Scene. I have another view controller named as Login Scene. Now want to push from my Home Scene to Login Scene after 5 secs from running my project. I have created a manual segue from Home Scene to Login Scene and gave the identifier name as login. Now when I am running my project, just after running it is pushing from Home Scene to Login scene and after 5 secs my project is crashing and the error is coming as, "'Receiver () has no segue with identifier '''. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

I have done this code in my .m file

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
[self performSelector:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)
           withObject:self afterDelay:5];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dispatch_after()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) instead of `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
});
```

---

When you called perform selector they way you did

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)
           withObject:self afterDelay:5];
```

Only one parameter is passed in the message.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:self sender:nil];
```

Obviously not what you intended.

---

**UPDATE**

`dispatch_after()` is one of many [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) functions. GCD uses [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) and [queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW66) to run code (dispatching) on different threads and/or at different times. A block is an anonymous function which can be stored in a variable and passed around as a parameter. A queue is a managed pool of threads. At runtime, a block of code is dispatched on a queue. In this case, the perform segue is dispatched on the main thread after a 5 second delay.

```
int64_t fiveSeconds = 5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC;

dispatch_time_t fiveSecondsFromNow = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, fiveSeconds); 
dispatch_queue_t onMainThread = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_block_t performSegue = ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
};

dispatch_after(fiveSecondsFromNow, onMainThread, performSegue);
```

Comment: Can you please get me understood with the method "dispatch_after()"? I just want to know what is it doing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourLoginController"];
   //use your rootViewControll here to load your view
   [self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [self performSelector:@selector(pushNewVC)
       withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}



-(void)pushNewVC {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{    
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
}
```

Try this code

Comment: I unaccepted just because when it is running, for a fraction of seconds the view going off and then again coming.